# PyCharm on macOS when running Selenium: Bad CPU type in executable

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver, macos-ventura

On macOS Ventura (version 13.4.1) with an M2 Pro chip with arm64 architecture, I`m trying to run tests by using

- PyCharm 2023.2 Community edition,
- Selenium robot framework 6.11,
- Python 3.11.4,
- Web driver manager installed with Chrome browser (version 15.0.5790.170 (Official Build) (arm64) )
- and compatible version of chrome web driver(arm64).

After running a test getting the following error :

```
OSError: [Errno 86] Bad CPU type in executable: '/Users//PycharmProjects/python/selenium_mini_course/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/macos/selenium-manager'
```

Can anybody Clarify? 
Thanks.

Spent about 3 hours navigating GPT, checked all versions for compatibility, Official source for Chromium and Selenium, retyped scripts in python, reactivated the virtual environment, pip all the libraries and...
Still nothing...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use a driver with a different architecture, mostly this error occurs in this case

try to get driver with proper arch https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

the second case 
If the executable is built for arm64 and you're running it on an x86_64 system (like the GitHub Actions runners), you might need to use Rosetta 2 to execute arm64 binaries

And pay attention, if in the future you will perform tests on CI/CD, you will need to make a self hosted runner (Git hub action), or use a driver for x86_64 systems